# What is the Oradiag_<user> Folder?

Tags: directory, oracle11g

What is the Oradiag_ Folder that is generated in my WinSCP folder?

Why does it get generated? And is there away to delete it for good?

Every time I sign in, it comes back when I delete it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is oradiag_<user> folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520054/what-is-oradiag-user-folder)

Answer (score 3):

As of Oracle 11g oracle redefined the directory location for diagnostic and alert files:

> The database installation process has been redesigned to be based on the ORACLE_BASE environment variable. Until now, setting this variable has been optional and the only required variable has been ORACLE_HOME.
>
> With this feature, ORACLE_BASE is the only required input, and the ORACLE_HOME setting will be derived from ORACLE_BASE. This change streamlines how Oracle software installation is organized, thereby making ongoing management easier.
>
> This feature improves manageability by making default Oracle Database installations more compliant with Optimal Flexible Architecture (OFA) specifications.

Also:

> ORACLE_BASE and Diagnostic Destination configuration
>
> The directory that you specify when you are prompted for ORACLE_BASE by Oracle Universal Installer is stored in the Oracle home inventory. Database Configuration Assistant uses this value to derive the default database locations and the DIAGNOSTIC_DEST parameter. The diagnostic destination location contains all ADR directories (diagnostic files such as Alert logs and so on). Starting with Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1), the initialization parameter settings for background dump, user dump, and core dump destinations are replaced by the Diagnostic Destination.

Reference:
[Oracle 11g Database New Features](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#FEATURENO08539)